# Send key input to HTML5 game using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, phaser-framework

I am trying to use Selenium to send key inputs to an HTML5 game I created using Phaser. However, I am quite puzzled why I can't get it to work. The same code works when I try on 2048 or other websites like google, python etc (but not on other HTML5 games built via phaser). Any tips or pointers would be super useful!

Below the python code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://dry-anchorage-61733.herokuapp.com/") #this is game link
#driver.get("https://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048/") #works for 2048
actions = ActionChains(driver)
for _ in range(6):
    actions.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_UP).perform()
    time.sleep(1)
    actions.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_LEFT).perform()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like selenium doesn't focus on your app.
Try clicking on the element and chain with sending keys

```
element = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("canvas")
actions.click(element).key_down(Keys.ARROW_LEFT).perform()
```

This worked for me

Comment: I can't thank you enough - I spent a lot of time trying to get Selenium to work for my game and it finally works. From the bottom of my heart a deepest thanks!!!!

Comment: Btw, out of curiosity - what is the difference between send_keys and key_down? Even after clicking on the canvas, send_keys method doesn't work but the key_down method works.

Comment: `key_down` only triggers the event of pressing a key(similar to pressing a key on keyboard and holding it)
`send_keys` on the other hand should trigger both key_down and key_up succesively. I'm not sure now why wouldn't it work